# Skinify Rig Options Not Visible in Pose Mode Blender 2.8

Tags: pose-mode

After enabling the rigify and skinify add-ons, the skinify options are not visible on the right side panel.Obviously, unable to add mesh to the armature.

Answer (score 1):

I found the *Skinify* options under the *Create* tab on the *3D View Sidebar* (<kbd>N</kbd> key).

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos  Thanks for the correct answer. How could I have missed that tab? It was there all along staring at me, bigger than life.